# Which is correct: "... where a is a constant" or "... where a is some constant"

Tags: grammar, mathematics

I noticed both of them are used in academic papers.

If both of them are correct, is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Usually 'some constant' introduces "some constant where ..." or "some constant defined by.." That's a certain fixed number, not just any fixed number. If you are defining *a* as a constant, then 'a is constant' is all you need to set a as any constant.

Comment: Both versions are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight nuance, in that the word "some" implies that some choice is possible.  Compare:

1. The ratio of the input voltage to the output frequency is **a constant**, whose exact value depends on the purity of the material, *vs*
2. The ratio of the input voltage to the output frequency is **some constant**, whose exact value depends on how finely the machinist followed the specifications.

Another way of looking at this is to form a sentence referring to a well-known constant where no "choice" is possible.  For example:

1. The number of pennies in a dollar is **a constant**,  *vs*
2. The number of pennies in a dollar is **some constant**.

The second form seems strange to the ears.  Either that, or it serves to introduce some speculative work in theoretical economics...